# My native method isn't being found by the Java end

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My native method isn't being found by the Java end

My subclass of `Activity` has:

```
package com.dumb_dumber.myproject;

public class SubActivity extends SDLActivity {//which extends Activity

    private static native void nativeInitGPGS(SubActivity act);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        nativeInitGPGS(this);
    }
```

While `main.cpp` begins, after first preprocessing directives:

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT void
Java_com_dumb_1dumber_myproject_SubActivity_nativeInitGPGS(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject activity)
{
```

I know I've inserted a 1 to make it `dumb_1dumber`, that's what Javah told me to do and has worked in the past, with a different framework. I've tried removing the 1 to no effect.

Still I get:

10-17 16:12:38.051: D/dalvikvm(4980): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.dumb_dumber.myproject/lib/libmain.so 0x423849c8
10-17 16:12:38.055: D/dalvikvm(4980): Added shared lib /data/data/com.dumb_dumber.myproject/lib/libmain.so 0x423849c8
10-17 16:12:38.060: V/SDL(4980): onCreate():null
10-17 16:12:38.087: W/dalvikvm(4980): No implementation found for native Lcom/dumb_dumber/myproject/SubActivity;.nativeInitGPGS:(Lcom/dumb_dumber/myproject/SubActivity;)V
10-17 16:12:38.108: D/AndroidRuntime(4980): Shutting down VM
10-17 16:12:38.108: W/dalvikvm(4980): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b73908)
10-17 16:00:52.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 16:00:52.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4699): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.dumb_dumber.myproject.SubActivity.nativeInitGPGS:(Lcom/dumb_dumber/myproject/SubActivity;)V
10-17 16:00:52.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4699):     at com.dumb_dumber.myproject.SubActivity.nativeInitGPGS(Native Method)
10-17 16:00:52.456: E/AndroidRuntime(4699):     at com.dumb_dumber.myproject.SubActivity.onCreate(SubActivity)

I believe the native implementation can be placed anywhere and automagickly picked up. I've tried placing the C implementation in another cpp body, instead of `main.cpp` but nothing changes.

Here is my `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
                    main.cpp
#Other stuff removed for clarity

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=   SDL2_image \
                            SDL2    \
                            SDL2_ttf
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += gpg_static

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

While I leave loading of the shared libraries to `SDLActivity`

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("SDL2");
    System.loadLibrary("SDL2_image");
    System.loadLibrary("SDL2_ttf");
    System.loadLibrary("main");
}
```

It's taken me ages to get here and I've built a lot of nice cpp in anticipation of a satisfactory solution but I realise it might not be possible, not by me at least. I've [remembered to run ndk-build](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4455/no-implementation-found-error-in-opencv-android/?answer=4478#post-id-4478) (twice) in the jni directory and am attempting to run on my phone.

I've run my libmain.so through a hexeditor and can confirm it exists, with the _1 in place. Not much more I can try, but having the time to experiment a little means I can try dropping the underscore. Tried it now, again, no difference.

Here's the first six lines output from `nm`, thanks Alex,

> ```
>     U IMG_Init  
>     U IMG_Load  
>     U IMG_Quit
> ```
>
> 00065454 T JNI_OnLoad
>   0005c208 T Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit
>   0006851c T Java_com_dumbdumber_myproject_SubActivity_nativeInitGPGS

```
                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE** Yep thanks again Chris, `myproject` was ommitted after you flagged my original activity type name / `jobject` parameter.

Comment: Android NDK comes with a utility `nm` that takes a parameter `-D`. Then you can see the list of exported functions of your `.so`, and check of their name s are not mangled the way you did not expect.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn It's right there as predicted, I'll update the op

Comment: You've shown it with an extraneous "1", and with no underscore, but not with just the underscore matching the package name.  Or with no underscore on *either* the native *or Java* side.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As I say, I've tried everything, the last update, reading in order from the top down indicates I've abandonded using an underscore in my package name. Sorry it's not absolutely clear, trying not to write a library. I've also found the "extraneous 1" to be essential, with a different framework, by which I mean instead of SDL, not Java or something. That's literally __everything__ I can think of tried. I'll be moving back to pure Java inevitably. :(

Comment: As you'll see if you build the hello-jni project from the NDK samples, this linkage works if you don't put extreme demands on it.  You say you've backed off from the underscore in the naming, but apparently have not yet gotten a completely clean rebuild based on that installed to test.  You also seem to have a mix of packages names which do and don't include "myproject" - that part is missing from your `nm` output for example.

Comment: Do you really need the underscore in the package name?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've seen it working, hence acceptance of the _1 rule. My only demand is `libSDL` and `gpg-cpp-sdk` to work together, the latter having a Java implementation I'll have to fall back to that until I've integrated gpg-cpp somewhere else from scratch. I've briefly tried running the `gpp-cpp` teapot and mininamlist samples but as they build on `NativeActivity` and I use `Activity` I gave up early on.

Comment: "My only demand is libSDL and gpg-cpp-sdk to work together" neither of those requires that you use a gratuitous underscore in the java package name of the class to which your custom native library belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Java_com_dumb_1dumber_myproject_SubActivity_nativeInitGPGS
```

does not match

```
package com.dumb_dumber.myproject;

public class SubActivity extends SDLActivity {//which extends Activity

   private static native void nativeInitGPGS(AnagrActivity act);
```

Hence the no implementation found error.

**Remove the extraneous "1" from your native method name**.  Also consider choosing a more reasonable package name **without an underscore in it**.

> > I've run my libmain.so through a hexeditor and can confirm it exists, with the _1 in place

Indeed, it would.  While your error trace clearly shows that the linker is looking for a function without that extraneous character.  Perhaps this is a quirk of implementation difference between Java vs Dalvik or ART - regardless, **you experience it only as a result of an unnecessarily novel** package name.

Comment: I felt it entirely necessary seeing as it was my recently purchased domain name. I've updated the question to show the effect of removing the underscore altogether. As I said originally, I had already tried both naming conventions, with and without the __extraneous__ 1

Comment: Your java package name does not need to match your domain name (which you stand a fair chance of losing in trademark proceedings anyway).  Nor does your native code and the class to which it belongs need to belong to the same package name as other parts of your java code.

Comment: I thought the idea was every domain name owner would get a unique package name. Obviously hard to enforce, but I was trying to comply with that simplistic ideal.

Comment: Again, the package name of your internal functionality does not have to match that of your apk itself.  Only the later needs to be unique - you can have a component such as com.globallyunique.name/com.overused.example.MyActivity and JNI will only see the package name of the class, not the uniquely-named package of the containing apk.

Comment: Thanks for repeating that, I'm sure you're right on the money, I'm just being thick, are you saying the package name in my manifest can represent the underscore in my domain name while my java package can be named independently?

Comment: Yes.  For internal components not in the apk's package name, you will just have to make sure your Activity (etc) declarations in your manifest give the full java package names for those, rather than using the "." shortcut (which would cause Android to look for them in the apk's package name).

Comment: Thanks, and you know what? I was using the wrong package name (from my last project) all along. So much repetitious rewriting of my makefile (new to me) to actually get `gpg` found I completely overlooked the obvious. Thanks for  bearing with me.